# InnoDB versus MyISAM

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb, myisam

In my particular situation I have a small website of about 6000 registered users. The FK constraints of InnoDB are useful to ensure data integrity, but I'm not sure what other benefits there could be... Especially since I'm losing out on FULLTEXT search, which could be very useful for me.

Is it worth changing my tables over to MyISAM in order to make use of FULLTEXT, or are there other benefits of InnoDB that mean I should make do with my `LIKE %keyword%` search solution?

(Note: The site is hosted on shared hosting, and so I don't think 3rd party search solutions like Sphinx are viable.)

Comment: In MySQL 5.6 InnoDB full-text searches seem to be supported: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html . When will it arrive on your shared hosting is another question.

Comment: Are you doing your own regular backups?

Comment: @erjiang Not at the moment :(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of referring to wiki or other pages for comparisions, check their(MyISAM and InnoDB) limitations on dev.mysql.com

[Limits on InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html)

As for MyISAMs limitations, they are mostly on disk/column sizes.

1. Large files up to 63-bit file length are supported.
2. There is a limitation of 264 (1.8 * 1019) rows in a MyISAM table.
3. The maximum number of indexes per MyISAM table is 64.
4. The maximum number of columns per index is 16.
5. The maximum key length is 1000 bytes.

InnoDB is pretty much newer and has more support from MySQL team, so using it for smaller and easily recreatable/restorable tables is what I am practising right now. Datas which are more frequently updated/inserted still use MyISAM on my own server.

Comment: What about the loss of FK constraints? Is there any real fallout from that?

Answer (score 1):

According to this link, InnoDB does now support Full Text Search

http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/innodb-full-text-search-tutorial/

(note) I'm going to have to read through this a bit more as well, but should be an interesting read none the less.

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used only with InnoDB or MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.